# When an element is selected from the list, I want my other list to be filled

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvvm, knockout.js

I am writing a web project, I want my bottom list to be filled when an element is selected from my top drop-down list, how can I do that? I need to do this in the method.

```
 <div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                asd</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsB" runat="server" SelectMethod="Liste"
                                   ></asp:ObjectDataSource>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlB" CssClass="chzn-select" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsB" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListeleB" 
                                    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                dsa</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="deneme" DataTextField="Ad" DataValueField="id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Asd"></asp:DropDownList>

                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsN" runat="server" SelectMethod="ListeleN"
                                   "></asp:ObjectDataSource>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="chzn-select" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsN"
                                    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My code here. Thanks in advance.

```
public List<BirimDTO> ListeleB()
    {
        var cache = new SystemCacheManager();
        List<ORT_Organizasyon> lst = cache.Get<List<ORT_Organizasyon>>(SYSCACHE_B);
        //lst2.Add(new BirimDTO { BirimId = 0, BirimAdi = "Seçiniz..." });

        if (lst == null)
        {
            using (TVKEntities ctx = GetContext())
            {
                lst = ctx.ORT_O.Where(p => p.OTipId == 3).ToList();
                cache.Put(SYSCACHE_B, lst);
            }
        }

        return lst.OrderBy(p => p.BId).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: can you post the code behind?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question

Comment: `OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListeleB"` where is the code of that ListeleB function

Comment: I added the method you want at the bottom of my question.